# Windows 7 as Public Server

Tags: windows, ftp, tftp

I want to create a TFTP server on my computer, and I found a program named `TFTPD32` that can help me. But when I try to bind my local IP `(192.168.X.X)` to a public one as I see in a tutorial, it doesn't show as a possible choice in that program.

As far as I know, to make this to work you need to install a server OS like Windows Server 2008, and Windows 7 Ultimate is a client one.

Is there a way to configure Windows 7 Ultimate as a public server?
Or maybe I am doing something wrong?

P.S.: I am sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If you want to bind a local IP address to a WAN address, you have to do that in your router.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get that working in a LAN environment, then the solution is what ElGalivan said - take a look at the NAT table in your router.

Typically you need to do NAT over the UDP port 69 to your sever LAN IP address.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation

Answer (score 0):

Tftpd32 can only "bind" to IP addresses available to the Windows OS where Tftpd32 runs.

In the very unusual case that your host is directly attached to a public IP Tftpd32 sure will have that public IP available for binding.

In a more normal case your host will be behind a router/NAT etc then your host will only have private IPs (192.168.x.x) available. In this case you should forward certain IP ports in your router in order to let exterior users reaching your server services.

But please consider; you should never do this with TFTP; TFTP is a protocol not meant for Internet traffic. It is used in the early stages of PXE booting strategies in LANs (Local Area Networks).